# Please explain the behaviour of Rails's cache in this case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Imagine I have 5 tags: `tag1,tag2...tag5`. If I do the following:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("all.tags") { Tag.all }
```

and afterwards I write `Rails.cache.fetch("all.tags")`, I see the 5 tags. If I add another tag, and I try to fetch from the cache again, the new tag is also loaded. Why is that?

EDIT: Here's my actual code:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("autocomplete.#{term}") { puts "Cache miss #{term}"; Tag.starting_with(term) }
```

Where `starting_with` is doing a where to find tags starting with certain letters. Here's the behaviour I get in the console:

```
1.9.3p125 :046 > Rails.cache.read("autocomplete.ta")
  Tag Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (name like 'ta%')
 => [#<Tag id: 10, name: "tag1">, #<Tag id: 11, name: "tag2">, #<Tag id: 12, name: "tag3">, #<Tag id: 13, name: "tag4">]
1.9.3p125 :048 > Tag.create(name:"tag5")
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("name") VALUES (?)  [["name", "tag5"]]
   (150.9ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Tag id: 14, name: "tag5"> 
1.9.3p125 :049 > Rails.cache.read("autocomplete.ta")
  Tag Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (name like 'ta%')
 => [#<Tag id: 10, name: "tag1">, #<Tag id: 11, name: "tag2">, #<Tag id: 12, name: "tag3">, #<Tag id: 13, name: "tag4">, #<Tag id: 14, name: "tag5">]
```

Comment: How do you store your data in the cache? It has to be done via `Rails.cache.write('all.tags', Tag.all)`. Perhaps you misspelled you key when you stored the data to the cache.

Comment: I edited the question with an update. I'm not doing anything fancy with the cache ( as far as I can tell ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown the code for `Tag.starting_with_term` but I'd bet good money that it's a scope or returning something scope like, ie something along the lines of

```
Tag.where(...)
```

This is fundamentally different from the `Tag.all` i  your initial question: `Tag.all` is an array but the above is a scope. Scopes are evaluated lazily, the rows are only requested from the database when you call a method on the scope that requires the scope be an actual array.

What is happening here is that you are caching the actual scope, not the rows that scope would select. Another way of looking at it is to say that at the moment you are caching the conditions that make up the query, not the query results.

When you read from the cache your scope is retrieved from the cache and the act of trying to display it forces rails to evaluate it. This evaluation happens after the scope is retrieved from the cache so you always get fresh results.

The simplest thing is to force evaluation of the scope, ie something like

```
Rails.cache.fetch('cache_key') { Tag.starting_with(term).all }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible .

Cache worked on the key/value pair .

```
Rails.cache.fetch("all.tags") { Tag.all }
```

It will always return the value of stored key "all.tags" .

Can you try to read the value , that stored in cache or not . And then add new tags

```
Rails.cache.read("all.tags")
```

I know its not the answer as per your question, but I am also curious to know why its going to happened .

Are you doing any thing else with cache setting ?

Comment: Strange ... I have tried same thing but it works fine . Which version of rails are you using ?

Comment: 3.2.2 ... this is very strange.

Comment: Could this somehow be caused by the fact that I'm running in development?

Comment: I don't think so . As I know it works same in each environment.